# Bug of Firebug or Microsoft Optimization Framework?

Tags: firebug

I use Microsoft Optimization Framework. I inspected an app in Firebug and saw that bootstrap CSS cannot be loaded normally (at least Firebug thinks so). It shows the request as aborted.

But if I debug in Chrome or in the Firefox native dev tools then all looks OK.
The application loaded correctly in all cases. When I try to load the URL manually then all is also OK.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Looks like a bug in Firebug to me. Any chance for an online test case, so this can be reproduced? If you have one, you should [create a bug report](http://code.google.com/p/fbug/issues/entry) at the Firebug issue tracker.

Comment: I feel that it is Firefox bug. If my compilation is debug each *.css file should be loaded separately (not in bundle). But firefox tool does not display at all any requests to server (if it is CSS file).